# HTML Report for JUNIT by ANT

Tags: ant, junit

How can I generate HTML reports from JUnit using Ant when there are test failures?

The reports are generated when there are no failures.

Also, how can we define our own XSLT for the report generation?

**build.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="Ant Example" default="all" basedir=".">
    <property name="project_name" value="junitSamples" />
    <property name="src" location="src" />
    <property name="build" location="build/classes" />
    <property name="lib" location="lib" />
    <property name="reports" location="reports" />

    <target name="init" depends="clean">
        <mkdir dir="${build}" />
        <mkdir dir="${lib}" />
        <mkdir dir="${reports}" />
        <mkdir dir="${reports}/raw/" />
        <mkdir dir="${reports}/html/" />
    </target>

    <target name="compile" depends="init">
        <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build}" description="compile the source code ">
            <classpath>
                <fileset dir="lib">
                    <include name="**/*.jar" />
                </fileset>
            </classpath>
        </javac>
    </target>

    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="build" />
        <delete dir="${reports}" />
    </target>

    <target name="run-tests" depends="compile">
        <junit printsummary="yes" haltonfailure="yes" showoutput="yes">
            <classpath>
                <pathelement path="${build}" />
                <fileset dir="lib">
                    <include name="**/*.jar" />
                </fileset>
            </classpath>

            <batchtest fork="yes" todir="${reports}/raw/">
                <formatter type="xml" />
                <fileset dir="${src}">
                    <include name="**/*Test*.java" />
                </fileset>
            </batchtest>
        </junit>
    </target>

    <target name="test" depends="run-tests">
        <junitreport todir="${reports}">
            <fileset dir="${reports}/raw/">
                <include name="TEST-*.xml" />
            </fileset>
            <report format="noframes" todir="${reports}\html\" />
        </junitreport>
    </target>

    <target name="all" depends="clean, test" />
</project>
```

Comment: Is that really how your XML is indented? Please consider using consistent indentation, and spaces instead of tabs.

Answer (score 3):

To specify your own stylesheets, use the `"styledir"` attribute:

```xml
<report styledir="${resources}/junit" format="..." todir="..." />
```

As noted, you must use the `"junit-noframes.xsl"` stylesheet name.

[JUnit report docs](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junitreport.html).

Comment: I have done it , it is working fine now. Let me add the comment here for others , you have to use the following <junit printsummary="yes" haltonfailure="yes" showoutput="yes">  , if haltonfailure is false then the html report will only be generated when all the test-cases get passed

Comment: Thanks for that user1753210. You could consider adding your comment as an answer

Answer (score 1):

You set haltonfailure="yes" it means that if one test fails build operation will stop.
This is from the ant documentation:
"Stop the build process if a test fails (errors are considered failures as well)."
Read more here- https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html